# Image picker upload to firestore and display

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I had an activity that i converted over to a fragment.

CODE:

```
    mImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Image"), GALLERY_PICK);

        }
    });



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        String imageUri = data.getDataString();

        CropImage.activity(Uri.parse(imageUri))
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .start(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()));

    }

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog((getActivity()));
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Pleas Stand By");
            mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();

            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

            final String current_user_id = mCurrentUser.getUid();

            final StorageReference filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child(current_user_id + (".jpeg"));
            filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                            Map<String, String> newImageUrl = new HashMap<>();
                            newImageUrl.put("image", filepath.toString());

                            db.collection("Users").document(current_user_id)
                                    .set(newImageUrl, SetOptions.merge())
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "Image uploaded!");
                                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                            //Toast.makeText(user_profile.this, "Succesful Upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                            filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                                                    //The download url
                                                    final String downloadUrl =
                                                            uri.toString();
                                                    Log.d("tag", downloadUrl);
                                                    if (!downloadUrl.equals("default")) {
                                                        // I changed this to glide since i thought picasso was the problem.
                                                        // Picasso still should work. Glide is recommended by google tho
                                                        Glide.with(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext())).load(downloadUrl).into(mDisplayImage);
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            })
                                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                            Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
                                                         //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There was some error in saving Changes.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        }
                                                    });
```

What this code attempts to do is bring up an image picker allow the user to upload a image to firestore and then have the image displayed in a imageview

the app does not crash but no code is ran past this line `if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)`

I played around in the debugger attempting to diagnose the issue i found the `result code = 1`and the `Request code = -1` when i click on the `(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)` the `IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE` is equal to 203 there for not passing the conditions of the if statement. This code was working fine in the activity so im very confused on why it is not working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by replacing

```
.start(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()));
```

With

```
.start(getContext(), this);
```

This [github](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/76) post explains it in more detail